# How to most securely and effectively handle the data migration between different database versions / document structures?

Tags: pouchdb

Premise 1: The structure of your documents will change over time due to new features, updates, etc. 
 Premise 2: Not all user documents will end up on your server, because sync is a premium feature. 
Premise 3: The web or mobile client expects the data to come from the database in a certain structure to function properly.

--> I need to handle data migration on the client. 
--> I need to keep track of all database versions / document structures that ever existed and make sure that I migrate them safely to the current version, because otherwise the data corrupts and the app cannot be used anymore.
--> If something goes wrong, there is no easy way to solve it, because the data is on the client and I can't solve it from the server.

Solution 1: I store the version of the database in a document and create a 'migrateDB' function that checks the database version during startup and migrates all documents if needed. 
--> Requires less verbose code during subsequent database reads, because the client can expect the data to be safely migrated and in the right structure 
--> If something goes wrong during the migration, the app basically can't be used anymore

Solution 2: The client migrates the documents on demand by checking the structure on every read and updating them if the structure is not as expected.  
--> This would require very verbose code for reading documents from the database. It would have to handle every possible structure the data could still be stored in the database.  
--> You will end up with a database in which some documents still have the old structure (because they haven't been read yet), while others have already been migrated

Solution 3: Solution 1 + Solution 2

Solution 4: ?

How do you deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you find you need this level of data migrations on a schema-less document store, you're possibly not using it optimally.

Each consumer/client should encode in its logic its minimum requirements, and should ignore any additional fields.

So, for example, if a client requires the fields "name", "part-id" and "count" it should error if any of these aren't present, but function normally if a subsequent new feature adds new data fields to the document.

In a schema-less database, the cost of the flexibility is that "schema validation" is now all client-side, in code, rather than integrity guarantees in a schema.

Solution 4: expect and embrace the fact that your database will contain diverging document versions over time, and write your code to cope with that by being as permissive as possible. If it becomes unbearable, do a batch job migration to a unified structure at the source of truth.

Hint -- if you're asking PouchDB questions, also tag your question with CouchDB and Cloudant for maximum eyeballs.